# Switch to xCode5 with the new SDK will eliminate bugs?

Tags: ios7

I've just installed ios7 on my iPhone, however I have not yet downloaded xCode5, so I've been producing my archives using iOS6 SDK and using TestFlight to test them on my phone. When running my app on iOS7, I'm noticing a lot of bugs that I didn't see in iOS6 (some that are unpredictable and very difficult to fix). I've been avoiding downloading xCode7 because I'm not yet ready to make the commitment to the new UI elements, but I'm wondering if I did produce my app using the iOS7 SDK, is it possible some of these bugs could be eliminated?

Comment: 1) What problems, exactly, are you finding? 2) All iOS 7 beta bugs should be logged with Apple or at least published on the Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: @RoboticCat - Some issues with the UITapGestureRecognizer (it gets disabled) that seem to happen randomly and I'm having a hard time reproducing / fixing. I did file a bug report with Aapple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question. iOS 7, despite its advanced beta count, is still very much a work in progress. There are bugs that should be reported to Apple that should not happen. But beyond that, there are changes in the internal API that influence how the app behaves. Apple has done its best to try and preserve SDK 6 apps as much as possible, but there is breaking API which can cause crashes. One example off the top of my head is the class cluster they are now using with `ABPersonViewController`. Subclassing that in iOS 6 works fine, but in iOS 7, even when compiled with SDK 6, causes a crash in most cases. These issues can be resolved even with Xcode 4.6 and SDK 6.

Compiling with SDK 7 may help you fix some issues, but it will come with a plethora of issues of its own. Depending on how complex your view hierarchy is, you may have to invest a considerable amount of effort to support the new API and functionality. You don't really have a choice, as this is the future, but you should be prepared for this, and arrange your schedule accordingly.

Comment: +1: "you should be prepared for this, and arrange your schedule accordingly"... make sure to factor in extra time for developer portal downtime and "schedule maintenance"... :P